# How to make Contact Form Send Mail?

Tags: php, xampp, smtp, sendmail

So I have a contact Form that when all the info that is needed is and you press 'Send Message', it displays a message saying "Your message has been sent" but the in actuality it hasn't sent anything to the email that I want it sent to. Mailserver in xampp btw.

Front-End:

```
<?php
    if($message_sent):
?>
    <h3>Your message has been sent</h3>

<?php 
    else:
?>

<div class="Form-container">
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex="1" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control <?= $invalid_class_name ?? "" ?>" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jane@doe.com" tabindex="2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Hello There!" tabindex="3" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" cols="50" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Message..." tabindex="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Send Message!</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Backend:

```
<?php
    $message_sent = false;
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''){

        if( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $message = $_POST['message'];
            
            $to = "petrus9572@gmail.com";
            $body = "";

            $body .= "From: ".$name. "\r\n";
            $body .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
            $body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";

            mail($to,$subject,$body);

            $message_sent = true;
        }
        else{
            $invalid_class_name = "form-invalid";
        }
    }

?>
```

Sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=********@yahoo.com
auth_password=***********
```

php.ini:

```
SMTP=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = ********@yahoo.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Please use any email service provider like mailchamp, Sendgrid etc and set your smtp based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **phpMailer** package to configure your mail setting manually from project.
If your site isn't ssl certified then use **tls** instead of **ssl** and use **Mailtrap** for testing mail service.